# Override opacity in Qselect when disabled

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using the Quasar framework and want to use the Disabled option on the [q-select](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select) component, but i dont like that the text has some transparency. Is there a way to override it?. 
[image: q-select component]

I want the text to be like the above.

```
<q-select
    v-for="subscriber in filterByAgentCC(subscribers.isAgent === 0)"
    id="readonly"
    :key="subscriber.id"
    class="full-width"
    :subscribers="subscriber"
    dense
    :value="subscriber.contactName"
    label="CC"
    emit-value
    map-options
    hide-dropdown-icon
    outlined
    disable
    input-class="text-black"
    use-input
    fill-input
    hide-selected
  />
```

so I am using "disable" so the user cant access the select. But i want the transparency to be 1. I can change the text color at input-class but i have no idea how to do transparency

Comment: Provide your code example.

Comment: Editted my question

Answer (score 0):

As it exists an `options-selected-class`  in q-select it should have also an `options-disabled-class` imo.

Otherwise it will be difficult to make an CSS overwrite, if you aren't CSS expert.
I have the same problem and I want to have disabled items with `text-decoration: line-through` but w/o luck until now.